# Is it intended that CoefficientRules permutes exponent vectors when given a monomial order?

Tags: bugs, polynomials

**Bug introduced in 13.0 or earlier. Fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier.**

---

I noticed an odd behavior in `CoefficientRules` when you give it a monomial order:

```mathematica
In[1]:= r = CoefficientRules[t^2 + 3 u, {u, t}, "NegativeDegreeLexicographic"]
Out[1]= {{0, 1} -> 3, {2, 0} -> 1}

In[2]:= FromCoefficientRules[r, {u, t}]
Out[2]= 3 t + u^2
```

Without `"NegativeDegreeLexicographic"`, then the exponent vectors respect the `{u, t}` order and `FromCoefficientRules` results in the expected `t^2 + 3 u`.  Since `FromCoefficientRules` doesn't take a monomial ordering as an argument, this has the appearance of a bug, but I wanted to check that I wasn't missing something about `CoefficientRules` before reaching that conclusion.

Maybe a clearer example is this:

```mathematica
In[1]:= r = CoefficientRules[a + 2 b + 3 c + 4 d, {a, b, c, d},
  "NegativeDegreeLexicographic"]
Out[1]= {{0, 0, 0, 1} -> 1, {0, 0, 1, 0} -> 2, {0, 1, 0, 0} -> 
  3, {1, 0, 0, 0} -> 4}

In[2]:= FromCoefficientRules[r, {a, b, c, d}]
Out[2]= 4 a + 3 b + 2 c + d
```

It seems to be reversing the variables completely, maybe a consequence to how `"NegativeDegreeLexicographic"` might be implemented.

Comment: `FromCoefficientRules[r, {t, u}]` recovers the original expression.  "Possible Issues" in the documentation of `CoefficientRules` alludes to similar behavior.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I was using that as a workaround, but is this exponent vector permutation expected? The documentation says `FromCoefficientRules` is the inverse to `CoefficientRules`, and needing to change the variable order doesn't seem right. I had thought the "Possible Issues" section was referring to how when you don't give variables it will use `Variables`.

Comment: At the first sight, I would consider this either a bug or a weird undocumented behaviour. The same happens for ``"NegativeDegreeReverseLexicographic"``. Taking a look at Neat Examples for [`CoefficientRules`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientRules.html), one can see that they unfortunately chose same bounds up to 5. But if one changes them to ``{i, 0, 5}, {j, 0, 3}``, we can see that the result is [weird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtcV4.png) – the last two being transposed.

Comment: My vote is on "bug". Nobody gave `CoefficientRules` permission to change the variable order and not say anything about it.

Comment: Reported the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = CoefficientRules[t^2 + 3 u, {u, t}, "NegativeDegreeLexicographic"]
```

gives

> `{{1, 0} -> 3, {0, 2} -> 1}`

and

```
FromCoefficientRules[r, {u, t}]
```

returns

> `t^2 + 3 u`

Likewise for the other example from the OP.

A screenshot for clarity and completeness

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Nice to see it's been fixed!